# Finding all measure spaces satisfying a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find all $c\in[3,\infty[$ such that there exists a measure space with $\{\mu(E):E\in S\}=[0,1]\cup[3,c]$

I'm drawing a complete blank here, how could one begin to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\{µ(E) : E ∈ S\} = [0, 1] ∪ [3, c]$. Prove that $c ≥ 4$. Can you give an example of $(X, S, µ)$ if $c = 4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933982/%c2%b5e-e-%e2%88%88-s-0-1-%e2%88%aa-3-c-prove-that-c-%e2%89%a5-4-can-you-give-an-exampl)

Comment: Yeah thanks that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose any such measure $\mu$.

For each $\gamma\in[0,1]\cup[3,c]$, choose some $E_\gamma$ with $\mu(E_\gamma)=\gamma$.

Show that $\gamma\in[0,1]$ implies $\mu(E_\gamma\setminus E_1)=0$.

Show that $\mu(E_1\cap E_3)=0$.

Conclude that $c\geq 4$.

Show that if $c>4$, $\mu$ would take on a value in $(1,2).$

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try this